# SVG Path Overlay and Animate Out Another Path

Tags: javascript, html, svg, svg-animate

I have an SVG of a dashed gray line. What I want to do is overlay that on top of a green SVG dashed line, and animate out the gray to reveal the green. Sorta like a meter moving from right to left.

I saw this example of how to make a dash line:

http://jsfiddle.net/ehan4/2/

and was able to do it but my line is already dashed.

I ended up doing this:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
         viewBox="0 0 666.9 123.8" enable-background="new 0 0 666.9 123.8" xml:space="preserve">
    <path  opacity="0.4" stroke-width="3" fill="none" stroke="#66CD00" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="5" stroke-dasharray="1,6" d="
        M656.2,118.5c0,0-320.4-251-645.9-0.7" />
        <path id="top"  opacity="0.4" fill="none" stroke="#AEAEAE" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="5" stroke-dasharray="1,6" d="
    M656.2,118.5c0,0-320.4-251-645.9-0.7"/>

</svg>

var path = document.querySelector('#top');
var length = path.getTotalLength();
// Clear any previous transition
path.style.transition = path.style.WebkitTransition =
  'none';
// Set up the starting positions
path.style.strokeDasharray = 1  + ' ' + 6;
path.style.strokeDashoffset = length;

// Trigger a layout so styles are calculated & the browser
// picks up the starting position before animating
path.getBoundingClientRect();
// Define our transition
path.style.transition = path.style.WebkitTransition =
  'stroke-dashoffset 20s linear';
// Go!
path.style.strokeDashoffset = '0';
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ps5yLyab/

How can I overlay the two dash lines and animate out the gray?

Comment: alot of this is from tutorials. I am currently trying to tackle this from animating out the gray line.

Comment: You are not very clear on what you want to achieve.  Are you saying you want an animated grey dashed line that shrinks from right to left revealing an animated green dashed line?

Comment: Yes I want the dashed Grey line to disappear and show the green dashed line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with a clip path.

First we add a clipPath to the SVG.

```
<defs>
    <clipPath id="myclip">
        <rect id="cliprect" x="100%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%"/>
    </clipPath>
</defs>
```

This clip path is sized the same size as the SVG (width and height 100%) and starts with its x postion at the far right of the SVG (100%). So at the start it is not revealing anything.

Then every 10mS we reduce it's x coord by 1% (ie 100% -> 99% -> 98% etc). until it reached zero.

```
var cliprect = document.getElementById("cliprect");
var offsetX = 100;
var speed = 10;

function clipAdjust()
{
    cliprect.setAttribute("x", offsetX+"%");
    offsetX -= 1;
    if (offsetX >= 0) {
        window.setTimeout(clipAdjust, speed);
    }
}

window.setTimeout(clipAdjust, speed);
```

Working demo below:

```js
var path = document.querySelector('#top');
  var length = path.getTotalLength();
  // Clear any previous transition
  path.style.transition = path.style.WebkitTransition =
    'none';
  // Set up the starting positions
  path.style.strokeDasharray = 1  + ' ' + 6;
  path.style.strokeDashoffset = length;

  // Trigger a layout so styles are calculated & the browser
  // picks up the starting position before animating
  path.getBoundingClientRect();
  // Define our transition
  path.style.transition = path.style.WebkitTransition =
    'stroke-dashoffset 20s linear';
  // Go!
  path.style.strokeDashoffset = '0';

var cliprect = document.getElementById("cliprect");
var offsetX = 100;
var speed = 10;

function clipAdjust()
{
    cliprect.setAttribute("x", offsetX+"%");
    offsetX -= 1;
    if (offsetX >= 0) {
        window.setTimeout(clipAdjust, speed);
    }
}

window.setTimeout(clipAdjust, speed);
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
   viewBox="0 0 666.9 123.8" enable-background="new 0 0 666.9 123.8" xml:space="preserve">

    <defs>
        <clipPath id="myclip">
            <rect id="cliprect" x="100%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%"/>
        </clipPath>
    </defs>

    <path opacity="0.4" fill="none" stroke="#AEAEAE" stroke-linecap="round"
          stroke-miterlimit="5" stroke-dasharray="1,6" stroke-width="2"
          d="M656.2,118.5c0,0-320.4-251-645.9-0.7"/>

    <g clip-path="url(#myclip)">
        <path stroke-width="3" fill="none" stroke="white"
              stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="5"
              d="M656.2,118.5c0,0-320.4-251-645.9-0.7" />
        <path id="top"  opacity="0.4" stroke-width="3" fill="none" stroke="#66CD00"
              stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="5" stroke-dasharray="6,6"
              d="M656.2,118.5c0,0-320.4-251-645.9-0.7" />
    </g>
  
</svg>
```

Comment: Alright I'll try this out and post what happens here when I get the chance. Sounds like something that shud work. I'm just clipping out the Grey and showing the green as it clips down.

Comment: Actually the other way around. We are clipping out the green and showing more and more of it as the clip rectangle moves to the left.

Comment: This moves the green line perfectly. Now I think I can just hide the gray line as the green line moves across the screen. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Ah yes. I wasn't hiding the grey line properly, was I?  That's fixed now.  I am hiding it with a white line behind the green. But there are other ways, such as having two clip paths. One for green and one for grey.

Comment: beautiful i never messed with svg before. theres so much more possibilities with graphics now it seems with them.